# AssertionError in the kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I M trying to add  screen inside the screen manager but giving error of assertion when assigning navigation drawer in a screen manager.

This is the Error i am facing :
self._apply_rule(
File "/home/hp/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 559, in _apply_rule
assert(rule not in self.rulectx)
AssertionError

This is my Code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    MenuScreen:
    ProfileScreen:
    ContentNavigationDrawer:
<MenuScreen>:
    name: 'menu'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Profile'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.6}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'profile'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Upload'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'upload'
    
<ProfileScreen>:
    name: 'profile'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Profile'
        halign: 'center'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Back'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    name : 'upload'
    ScrollView:

        MDList:

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 1"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 2"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 2"


    Screen:

        MDToolbar:
            id: toolbar
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            elevation: 10
            title: "MDNavigationDrawer"
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

        NavigationLayout:
            x: toolbar.height

            ScreenManager:
                id: screen_manager

                Screen:
                    name: "scr 1"

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Screen 1"
                        halign: "center"

                Screen:
                    name: "scr 2"

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Screen 2"
                        halign: "center"

            MDNavigationDrawer:
                id: nav_drawer

                ContentNavigationDrawer:
                    screen_manager: screen_manager
                    nav_drawer: nav_drawer
"""


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ProfileScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ContentNavigationDrawer(Screen):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(ProfileScreen(name='profile'))
sm.add_widget(ContentNavigationDrawer(name='upload'))


class DemoApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen


DemoApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your rule in `screen_helper`:

```
<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
```

includes:

```
            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
```

That rule combination tells kivy that whenever it creates a `ContentNavigationDrawer` it should create another `ContentNavigationDrawer` as a child of the first. Then it would try to apply the original `<ContentNavigationDrawer>:` again, creating a third `ContentNavigationDrawer`, applying the rule again to create a fourth, and so on. This would create an infinite loop. Kivy uses the `assertion` to avoid such loops. So, you just cannot use a rule that would create such a loop.